# How to post observer from normal class and receive listener to widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to Flutter and experimenting with the SDK. I am working with the flutter application which works with Socket connection. I saw lots of example which communicate with widget to widget. But, I want to add listener from Socket class to widgets. The actual scenario is, I have **socket listeners** in my socket manager class. Here is the rough code for better idea.

```
  class SocketManager {

   static SocketIO socketIO;
   static SocketIOManager manager = SocketIOManager();

   //Constructor
   SocketManager(){
     initSocket().then((socketIO){
       addListener();
     });
   }

   void addListener(){
      socketIO.onConnect((data){
      print("connected...");
   });

   }

  }
```

I want to notify to my widgets when socket connected.
What kind of thing am I looking for to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is my class, you can follow to create yours

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_app/global.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/strings.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;



IO.Socket kSocket;

class Sockets {
  static PublishSubject socket = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject status = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject notify = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject chatCount = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject typing = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject login = PublishSubject(sync: false);
  static PublishSubject getInfo = PublishSubject(sync: true);
  static PublishSubject alreadyLogin = PublishSubject(sync: false);
  static void connectSocket() async {
    /* kSocket = await IO.io('${Strings.socket}', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket', 'polling'],
    });*/
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = prefs.getString('userToken');

    if (token != null && token != '') {
      Map<String, dynamic> parsedToken = Functions.parseJwt(token);

      String imza = token?.split('.')[2];
      kSocket = await IO.io('${Strings.socket}', <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket', 'polling'],
        'query': 'token=$imza'
      });

      parsedToken['Tur'] = 2;
      kSocket.close();
      kSocket.disconnect();
      kSocket.open();
      try {
        kSocket.on('connect', (data) {
          print('SOCKET CONNECTED');
          kSocket.emit('adduser', parsedToken);
          kSocket.on('getmessage', (res) {
            print('GETMSG: $res');
            chatCount.sink.add(res);
            socket.sink.add(res);
          });
          kSocket.on('bildirim', (res) {
            print('[BILDIRIM]: $res');
            notify.sink.add(res);
          });
          kSocket.on('durum', (res) {
            status.sink.add(res);
          });

          kSocket.on('disconnect', (data) {
           // print('DISCONNECT: $data');
          });

          kSocket.on('typing', (res) {
            typing.sink.add(res);
          });

          kSocket.on('login', (res) {
            //print('Multi Login');
            login.sink.add(res);
          });

          kSocket.on('getinfo', (res) {
            //print('GETINFO: $res');
            getInfo.sink.add(res);
          });

          kSocket.on('alreadylogin', (res) {
            //print('ALREADY LOGIN: $res');
            alreadyLogin.sink.add(res);
          });
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      print('SOCKET: token yok');
    }
  }

  static void setInfo(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    kSocket.emit('setinfo', [data]);
  }

  static void setRead(String userid) {
    kSocket.emit('setreaded', '$userid');
  }

  static void isTyping(String username, int status) {
    kSocket.emit('istyping', [
      {"user": int.parse(username), "durum": status}
    ]);
  }

  static void isActive(String userid) {
    if (kSocket != null) {
      if (kSocket.connected) {
        try {
          //print('${kSocket.connected}');
          kSocket.emit('isactive', '$userid');
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static void disconnectSocket() async {
    try {
      await kSocket.disconnect();
      await kSocket.close();
      await kSocket.destroy();
      print('SOCKET DISCONNECTED');
    } catch (e) {
      //print(e);
    }
  }

  static void dispose(){
    socket.close();
    status.close();
    //notify.close();
    chatCount.close();
    typing.close();
    login.close();
    getInfo.close();
    alreadyLogin.close();
  }

  static void unSubNotify(){
    notify.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: How can you get notified to widget when socket is connected?

Comment: kSocket.isConnected

Comment: I want to call function from widget when socket connection established. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: PublishSubjects acts like a stream, you can listen them with streambuilder in your page, then make some actions there

or : `notifySubject.listen((res){ //do some event here })`

Comment: can I have some code? coz i am new with streambuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here !! Here what I found while surfing on the web. [Flutter-NotificationCenter](https://github.com/netyouli/Flutter-NotificationCenter). An IOS type post and receive observer. It is Very helpful to other developers who want to post observer from anywhere and want to receive it to anywhere.

Comment: Maybe an obvious answer but where is the latest version listed? So I can add it to the dependencies list.

Comment: it does not support dependency. just copy notification_center.dart file and add to your project. Please upvote if it helps!